# importing settings file in reusable django app

Tags: python, django

I am creating a reusable django application which can be used in any django project, and storing some credentials in the settings.py file.

settings.py

```
# Django settings for mytestapp project.
...
...
...
ADMIN_USERNAME='someone'
ADMIN_PASSWORD='someone'
```

I want to use these credentials in my app. How can I import them ?

I have tried,

```
import settings.ADMIN_USERNAME
```

and

```
from django.conf import settings.ADMIN_USERNAME
```

But both are not working.

I tried to import these variables from eclipse using ctrl+1 , then these variables imported as,

```
from mytestapp.settings import ADMIN_USERNAME
```

How can I import these variables, if I don't know project name (in case `mytestapp`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
from django.conf import settings
```

Then you can access your constants like `settings.ADMIN_USERNAME`.

Comment: And just to be cautious, this may bring some side effects. This will fetch all settings from mytestapp, including some that you may not want. For example assume there are LOGGING settings in mytestapp, those settings will start to be used for your project unless you explicitly override them in your settings.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code). Don't try to import a setting by name; you should just import the `settings`:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

and refer to your specific settings as attributes:

```
settings.ADMIN_USERNAME
```